# SQL Server 2012 Constraint

Tags: sql, sql-server

How to implement this constraint?

I have a column `LastModifiedBy` (datatype `Int`) for which I want to restrict the data from `UserTable.UserId` and also allow null.

How to implement this in SQL Server 2012?

Thank you,
Eric

Comment: Is there some reason this isn't as simple as a foreign key?

Comment: No reason. Just I have implemented all the validations using constraint. So just thought to implement this using constraint.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[yourtable] WITH NOCHECK
ADD CONSTRAINT [usertable$FK_usertable_1]
FOREIGN KEY([LastModifiedBy]) REFERENCES [dbo].[UserTable] ([UserId])
```

This script alter your table (where you have LastModifiedBy) adding a constraint of foreing key type to point UserTable

Comment: It is important to note that if you use this you will NOT be able to delete rows from the UserTable without first deleting the child row or setting UserID to null in the child row.

Comment: @Sean that would be true if you implemented the stated requirement in some other way, too, like a constraint or a trigger...

Comment: Agreed 100%. My comment was intended as support for this answer and posted to make sure the OP actually understands this is what will happen based on what they are asking for. Far too often this kind of thing gets implemented and then backed out due to not understanding how these types of relationships are handled.